# Custom Taxonomy conditionals

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization

So I have setup a custom post type 'products' and custom taxonomies / categories 'defence' 'law & enforcement' and 'Commercial'.

I have using the following conditional to set some specific css and the correct banner for a product:

```
<?php if (has_term( 'defence', 'productcat', $post->ID )) { ?>
```

This works fantastic if the product is in one category.

Here's my problem - i have products in multiple categories so i would like a conditional to see how they got to my product page:

I have a menu down the left side on taxonomy landing page and on product page, as an example lets say i have product 1 in all 3 taxonomies; down the left hand side there will be the 3 parent taxonomies with the product underneath each one as a child.

What i would like to do is have a conditional to set my custom css / banner depending on where the product on the left menu is clicked; ie if product 1 under 'Defense' is click i would like to display the 'Defense' banner, same goes if it is clicked under the other 2 taxonomies.

Hope this makes sense.

In all honesty i don't think this is possible and products with multiple taxonomies will just have to have the default css and a rotating banner with all taxonomies which it belongs too.

Your time and help with this is appreciated

**Edit**
Just had a thought - if i can get the taxonomies to form part of my permalink ie domain.com/products/taxonomy/product i could use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ==
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to work around this and do what i need to do i installed a plugin (Custom Post Type Permalinks by Toto_unit) to add custom post types and custom taxonomies to my permalink structure.

For my conditionals i'm using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == to check the current url.

Hopefully this helps someone else.