# Conditional Logic Based on Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pods-framework

I’m working on a large site in which I need to create various lists of different pages in the sidebar. I registered a custom taxonomy using the Pods plugin called “Page Categories” (page_category), and have successfully generated the lists of pages required using WP_Query. So far, so good.

Where I’m stuck: Each of these lists is contained in a template part that needs to be conditionally included in sidebar.php based upon the value of the current Page Category.

What I have that isn’t working:

```
    <?php
      $display = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'page_category', 
      array('fields'=>'slug'));

      switch($display){
         case 'dining-area-1':
           get_template_part('sidebar', 'dining-one');
           break;
         case 'dining-area-2':
           get_template_part('sidebar', 'dining-two');
           break;
       }
     ?>
```

The result of this is that the first case takes effect on every page, regardless of whether or not the page is associated with that category.

Any ideas?

Comment: `wp_get_post_terms` returns an array of objects, not a string

Comment: @Milo Okay. `wp_get_post_terms` produces the same result, so obviously it's returning a string, either. I guess I'm confused as to why I can't simply use `get_the_terms` and check against the results.

Comment: Ah, hang on...think I've found the answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83922/custom-taxonomy-conditionals?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Milo was absolutely correct...the issue was that I wasn't getting a string to compare. The solution actually came from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83922/custom-taxonomy-conditionals?rq=1).

What this ultimately looked like in my scenario:

```
    <?php
        if(has_term('dining-1', 'page_category', $post->ID)){
          get_template_part('sidebar', 'dining-one');
        }
        elseif(has_term('dining-2', 'page_category', $post->ID)){
          //etc.
        }
    ?>
```